# Struts2+Spring3+Tiles3

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2, tiles2, struts2-spring-plugin

I would like to integrate tiles 3 to my web application spring3+struts2+hibernate,
but I don't have any idea of were to begin. All examples that I see use struts2 with tiles only, no integration of spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few inputs how to integrate it.

1. For Integrating Struts2 with Spring use [struts2-Spring plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/spring-plugin.html), all you need to have required spring jars and plugin, and your spring configuration file.Plugin document contains a basic start as how to configure it and how to use it, just follow those instructions and you are good to go (i am assuming you know how to use Spring )
2. Struts2 is independent of Hibernate and you are free to use it on your own way, though there are some plugins available , but i will suggest not to use them
3. For tiles there is again a plugin to take care of integration.

All these plugin will help you to integrate various technologies, but how to use them and how they work, you need to get know about them independently.

Comment: I already set up Spring and struts2 and hibernate, What i need is simply the configuration of tiles plugin

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337938/how-to-integrate-struts-2-with-tiles-3

Comment: What would Spring be doing with Tiles that would cause a Struts2+Tiles example to be invalid in your case?

Comment: I think I must add listener in web.xml ??

Comment: @user1310305: you need to add that for sure, have you even looked at the plugin? its clearly mentioned what needs to be done

Comment: thx a lot for your help, as you said, it was easy with the struts2-plugin