# jsp is not displayed when using iframe

Tags: jsp, iframe

I am using the iframe and created four frames in homePage.jsp like this...

```
<body>
        <iframe name="headerContent" src="pages/header.jsp"  class="headerStyle" scrolling=no frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
        <iframe name="menuContent"   src="pages/menu.jsp"    class="menuStyle" scrolling=no frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
        <iframe name="menuContent2"  src="pages/content.jsp" class="contentStyle" scrolling=no frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
        <iframe name="footerContent" src="pages/footer.jsp"  class="footerStyle" scrolling=no frameborder=0 marginwidth=0 marginheight=0></iframe>
</body>
```

and have a menu.jsp which contains 4 links and when i click on one link and in href tag i am calling the action(which is defined in struts.xml) and this action is calling a class which is returning some data and on the SUCCESS it is forwarding to a CUSTOMERMAIN.jsp file but beacuse of iframe it is not displaying any jsp file.

If i don't use the iframe ..it is working fine and displaying the jsps properly....

Answer (score 1):

1. Your iframes should call Action classes, not JSP directly, because that's how an MVC framework, and Struts2 in particular, works;
2. You are reinventing the wheel, what you are trying to do is an ugly version of **TILES**.

Read more on:

[Struts with Tiles Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-tiles-framework-example/)

[Hot to integrate Struts2 with Tiles3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337938/how-to-integrate-struts-2-with-tiles-3)

[Tiles 3 Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/tiles-3-plugin.html) (since the doc is a work in progress, read [Tiles 2 Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/tiles-2-plugin.html))