# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/FileManagerProvider

Tags: xml, jsp, struts2

I have done a project using struts2. Now I am trying to incorporate tiles into my project, so I started learning tiles. I am getting following error in console while building my first sample pages itself.

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/config/FileManagerProvider
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_FileManager(Dispatcher.java:352)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:481)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1862)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.FileManagerProvider
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
... 20 more
```

Going over Internet I thought error may be because of jars I am using... So I am posting my jars too.

[image]

My struts.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

<package name="default" extends="struts-default">


    <result-types>
        <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
    </result-types>

    <action name="*Link" method="{1}" class="com.classes.JustJsps">
        <result name="welcome"  type="tiles">welcome</result>
        <result name="login"    type="tiles">login  </result>
    </action>

</package>
</struts>
```

My tiles.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="welcome" template="/baseLayout.jsp">  
    <put-attribute name="title"     value="DReST" type="string" /> 
    <put-attribute name="myHeader"  value="/head.jsp"/>   
    <put-attribute name="myMenu"    value="/menu.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="myBody"    value="/home.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="myFooter"  value="/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>  
<definition name="login" extends="welcome">
    <put-attribute name="myBody"    value="/login.jsp"/>
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns     /javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     id="WebApp_ID" 
     version="3.0">

<display-name>Tiles</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-    class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=welcomeLink.action">
```

`welcomeLink.action` returns 'welcome'. What is the mistake I am doing?

Comment: May be your missing some jar file in your classpath or project is not compile well.

Comment: Add `xwork-core` jar with same version as S2.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to use Tiles 2, you need [Struts2-tiles-2-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/tiles-2-plugin.html);
- If you want to use Tiles 3, you need [Struts2-tiles-3-plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/tiles-3-plugin.html).

Also pay attention to use the right configuration (listener, result, etc.): read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13337938/1654265) for more details.