# Struts tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files

Tags: java, jsp, maven, struts2, tiles

I am using Struts2 in Eclipse IDE and JBoss5 server and maven for build. I was trying to use tiles in a simple login application. But I am not able to include the taglib. I have imported all the necessary jars dependencies in `pom.xml` file. Following is the list of jars which I have included in maven `pom.xml` file:

- struts2-core 2.3.15.1
- struts2-tiles-plugin 2.3.15.1
- commons-beanutils
- struts-taglib
- commons-digester
- commons-beanutils
- tiles-api

and also I included and tried different possible combinations of

1. tiles-api-2.0.3.jar
2. tiles-core-2.0.3.jar
3. tiles-jsp-2.0.3.jar
4. struts-tiles.jar

and still it is not working, the Errors are :

```
-The absolute uri: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
-ServletException including path '/layout.jsp'. 
-ServletException including path '/layout.jsp'.
```

when I am trying to import tiles `taglib` on a JSP page it says

> URI: `http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles` cannot be resolved in
>   either `web.xml` or the jar files deployed with this application.

I tried Google also. Got some solutions but they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use servlet API at least version 2.4. In the tiles you could use taglib definition

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
```

Don't mess up Struts 1 taglib and tiles jars with [Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/) artifacts.

Comment: Hi Roman, I agree with your solution and thanks for giving hint on Deployment descriptor version...,
<br>

Comment: Hi Roman,
Do you have any idea on Maven build process...., while deploying the project in Jboss server,  some jars are showing like  not readable by server... I am getting exception like " java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 1731 but got 1706 bytes) " , Please help me out if you know the solution.

Comment: First I would test zip file with a command line utility, like jar or pkzip, second from maven you can download md5 or sha1 files and use it to check with checksum utility, third download libraries from the official distributor.

Comment: Hi @RomanC I have this problem, I create other thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63361221/jboss-deployment-structure-xml-and-global-module-wildfly-20), there I explaint my problem step by step if you or anyone want let's me support

Comment: In most cases you don't understand how to use tiles integration. It is also not clear which version of tiles and plugin is applied. If you have problems with tiles then you probably have to start reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42008939/573032) answer.

Comment: @RomanC I'm using struts2-core-2.5.22.jar, struts2-tiles-plugin-2.5.22.jar, and tiles 3.0.7 jar files, my project is deploy and run without problem but, when I call a fragment tiles that read <%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %> fail, in this way, I have org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener in web.xml, I dont have used maven for this project, I can tell you that server is wildfly-20 and if I set global-modules work fine, thank you by your comments

Comment: This is a JSP directive to use taglib definitions for your tiles tags inside jsp-s. It's required if you use `tiles` prefix to the JSP tags. You should be aware of the tiles tags when you use tiles framework. In the previous version of struts the tiles framework was integrated internally but in Struts2 you have to integrate it externally via plugin. I recommend to get started with Struts2 and tiles via reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36135554/573032) and liked answers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to integrate Struts2 with Tiles3.

See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Tiles+3+Plugin

and

[How to integrate Struts 2 with Tiles 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337938/how-to-integrate-struts-2-with-tiles-3)