# Error in Struts 2 app with Tiles: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/listener/TilesListener

Tags: java, struts2, listener, tiles

I am getting this error, although I've already put necessary jar files for Tiles:

```
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app 
SEVERE: Undeployment failed for context /FinalTilesStruts2 
SEVERE: Exception while loading the app : 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/listener/TilesListener
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: i am getting this error  as i mentioned above in title,TilesListener  class not found ?

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
SEVERE:   Undeployment failed for context /FinalTilesStruts2
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/listener/TilesListener

Comment: I've edited your question, because you didn't. See the answer below and accept it as soon as you read it.

Answer (score 1):

The class `org.apache.tiles.listener.TilesListener` only available in the Tiles 2.0.3 that you can download [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tiles/tiles-core/2.0.3/tiles-core-2.0.3.jar).

In higher versions of Tiles the listener class is `org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener`.

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32358332/573032) answer if it help you resolve problem with the right listener class.

If you are using Tiles 2 with Struts 2 then you should use

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```