# Struts2 tiles plugin and tiles configuration file in subfolders issue

Tags: struts2, tiles, apache-tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

[As release note reports:](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Version+Notes+6.3.0)

> This version embeds the Apache Tiles by directly coping the source code of the library. The Apache Tiles project has retired and right now it's in the attic - no development is happening around this project. Struts committers decided to copy all the required source code to continue undisturbed support for the the Struts 2 Tiles plugin.

So i want to clean up my app from old tiles libs and full migrate to Struts Tiles plugin, but if i replace the old listener (not included in new libs)

```
org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener
```

with

```
org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
```

The listener founds only `tiles\*.xml` definition in `WEB-INF` folder and ignore subfolders (for example `WEB-INF/foo/tiles/tiles-foo.xml`)

I try to use this parameter configured with the pattern of old `CompleteAutoloadTilesListener` but does not work because it expects a single file or a list and not a pattern.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.tiles.definition.DefinitionsFactory.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/**/tiles*.xml,classpath*:META-INF/**/tiles*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

At the moment the only way to make it work is to indicate the entire list of `tiles*.xml` but this is an old application and i have so many files, i risk losing some.

I can try to leave the only tiles-extras and continue to use the old CompleteAutoloadTilesListener, but i think i may run into future compatibility issues.

Has anyone found a workaround?

thanks

Comment: It is not clear your problem. If you need to use tiles plugin you should figure out the version of tiles See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36135554/573032) answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify any params for configuration. The definitions should be placed in `WEB-INF` or `resources` using `tiles*.xml` pattern.

> [**Tiles plugin - Usage**](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles/):
>
> As from Struts 2.3.28, the plugin automatically loads all Tiles definitions matching the following pattern `tiles*.xml`.

Comment: yes, but with org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener  i can put in subfolder, now with struts2-tiles-plugin only in web-inf root folder (or resoruce)

Comment: You should use org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964006/573032) answer.