# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.setApplicationContext(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)V

Tags: struts2, migration, struts, apache-tiles, struts2-tiles-plugin

Migration from Struts 2.3.37 to Struts 2.5.33.
I have referred to the given below page
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/Struts+2.3+to+2.5+migration
and I am getting error while running on Tomcat (v9.0.45)

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.setApplicationContext(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)V
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:114)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:64)
    at org.apache.tiles.web.startup.AbstractTilesListener.contextInitialized(AbstractTilesListener.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4716)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

I have referred to the given above link.

Answer (score 1):

The error is

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.setApplicationContext(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)V

because you have old tiles libraries somewhere on the classpath. May be you have packaged them to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. It might be Tiles 2.2. In the link you have posted is written:

> Depending on from which version of struts you upgrade and whether you used tiles-plugin or tiles3-plugin you may need to do different steps.
>
> Struts 2.5 just provides a tiles-plugin which uses Tiles3. So support for Tiles2 has been dropped as well as the name tiles3-plugin.
>
> Now the only Maven dependency looks like this
>
> **maven dependecy for tiles-plugin:**
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
>    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
>    <version>${struts2.version}></version>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> You may need to update DTD in your tiles.xml files to Tiles3:
>
> **tiles3.dtd:**
>
> ```
>    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
> ```
>
> A Listener in web.xml is required. It is not necessary to configure paths to tiles.xml files here as they are picked up automatically.
>
> **StrutsTilesListener in web.xml:**
>
> ```
> <listener>
>  <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
> </listener>
> ```
>
> Optionally you may remove TilesDefinitions from XML and annotate actions instead. See [Tiles Plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/tiles) for more details.