# JspTaglib ["http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"] is undefined: It cannot be assigned to tiles

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker, apache-tiles, tiles2

I'm doing an update conversion to a very old Java project and converting it under Spring Boot. But, I'm having difficulties getting the front pages to be render as they were built with Struts 2, `.ftl` using Apache Tiles.

For some reason I get this error [JspTaglibs](http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles) is undefined. It cannot be assigned to tiles, when it tries to load the page.

I have checked that I had all the `jar` files necessary (I think?), but as I'm not at all familiar with `.ftl` or tiles I can't help myself to figure out what is the problem.

**Dependencies:**

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

I'm assigning the tiles to the page like this

```freemarker
<#assign tiles=JspTaglibs["http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"]>

<@tiles.insertAttribute name="navigation" /> 

<@tiles.insertAttribute name="body" />
```

Comment: What difficulties?

Comment: `freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Error on line 33, column 1 in layout/layout.ftl
JspTaglibs["http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles"] is undefined.
It cannot be assigned to tiles`  seems to be the error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `web.xml` or bootstrup this servlet with Spring Boot.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jspSupportServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

---

It's needed to integrate Freemarker with Tiles in Struts 2.

You can use [struts-examples](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples) tiles project that demonstrates such integration. Also upgrade to the latest Struts version.

The sensible part of this project you can find in `pom.xml`.

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <struts2.version>2.5.8</struts2.version>
</properties>
```

---

Comment: Thank you Roman for the answer. I actually had that part on my web.xml. Now that I looked more closely of the error I feel stupid. It is actually cause by Jetty before and this only a result of it. Allthough i dont know how to fix it yet...

 `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1242) ~[jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:567) ~[jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar:9.2.19.v20160908]`

Comment: You didn't try the example from this answer. The jetty version is 8.1.16.v20140903

Comment: I tried to check the tiles example from your link and my web.xml has mostly the same part for the exception im using `<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>`with some params instead of `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

Comment: I also updated my struts and freemarker version and started using StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter, but that didn't seem to be the issue

Comment: I don't know what is the issue except version 2.5.9-SNAPSHOT is not downloadable from the maven central. At least it's not configured to download snapshots by default and use release-only mode.

Comment: @Oliver The issue may be is Struts version too old, Update it.