# jboss-deployment-structure.xml and global-module wildfly 20

Tags: module, struts2, tags, wildfly, tiles

I have been looking for witch is diferrent between global modules of wildfly 20 and jboss-deployment-structure.xml, I have several module define in my server then I have builded a project without maven setting my onw dependencies, then When I declared global project's modules in standalone file all works perfectly, but when I comment this on standalone, and declare this inside of subdeployment j-d-s.xml, The project dont work with tag-tiles or struts tag, this throw org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/tl/bas.jsp'.

jboss-deployment-structure.xml (version.1.0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment> -->
    <sub-deployment name="project.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="own.org.apache.tiles" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.struts2" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.commons" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.logging" />
            <module name="own.freemarker" />
            <module name="own.javassist" />
            <module name="own.ognl" />
        </dependencies>
    <!-- <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions> -->
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml (version.1.1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="own.org.apache.tiles" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.struts2" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.commons" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.logging" />
            <module name="own.freemarker" />
            <module name="own.javassist" />
            <module name="own.ognl" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment> 
    <sub-deployment name="project.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="own.org.apache.tiles" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.struts2" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.commons" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.logging" />
            <module name="own.freemarker" />
            <module name="own.javassist" />
            <module name="own.ognl" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

snippet code standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:5.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="own.org.apache.struts2" slot="main"/>
                <module name="own.org.apache.commons" slot="main"/>
                <module name="own.org.apache.logging" slot="main"/>
                <module name="own.freemarker" slot="main"/>
                <module name="own.javassist" slot="main"/>
                <module name="own.ognl" slot="main"/>
                <module name="own.org.apache.tiles" slot="main"/>
            </global-modules> 
<subsystem/>
```

server.log

```
2020-08-12 09:25:44,414 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/til/bf.jsp'.
...
2020-08-12 09:25:44,418 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Caused by: java.io.IOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/til/bf.jsp'.
...
2020-08-12 09:25:44,418 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)     at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:63) ~[tiles-request-servlet-1.0.7.jar!/:1.0.7]
...
2020-08-12 09:25:44,418 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004113: The absolute uri: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
...
2020-08-12 09:25:44,421 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2020-08-12 09:25:44,420 DEBUG [default task-1] dispatcher.DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler (DefaultDispatcherErrorHandler.java:108) - Exception occurred during processing request: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/til/bf.jsp'.
...
2020-08-12 09:25:44,421 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/til/bf.jsp'.2020-08-12 09:25:44,421 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/til/bf.jsp'.
...
2020-08-12 09:25:44,424 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Caused by: java.io.IOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/jsp/til/bf.jsp'.

...

2020-08-12 09:25:44,424 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004113: The absolute uri: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

The question is, Why jboss-deployment-structure.xml don't work with dependencies for the tiles setting and global-modules in standalone yes???

PD: The projects is deploying successly with both setting, jboss-deployment-structure.xml or global-modules but tiles tags don't work with jboss-deployment-structure.xml setting dependencies

Comment: Jboss is a different appserver than others. To see errors you should look into server.log. then post em here. Without error loogs it's difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: @RomanC add line of server.log, thank anyway

Comment: Are you including any JAR's in your EAR that require any of the modules? Using global modules adds those modules to all deployments where as the in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` you're only adding these to your WAR.

Comment: Hi @JamesR.Perkins, I did three setting firstable. only  jboss-deployment-structure.xml with call modules inside deployment tag. second. only  jboss-deployment-structure.xml with call modules inside sub-deployment tag that is j-d-s.xml that I did post and third any of previous setting plus global-modules declare. In three cases the deploy is successfull, but request tiles only work in 
third setting that I say it...

Comment: If you're deploying an EAR each sub-deployment that needs these dependencies would need to be defined. That would likely explain why the global modules work because the dependencies are added to all deployments. Meaning the EAR itself, plus all it's sub-deployments.

Comment: I was try with jboss-deployment-structure.xml ver 1.0 and 1.1.....in all cases ear is deployed but if dont declare global-modules request tiles fail...@JamesR.Perkins

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins in this way only if ear-subdeployments-isolated if it's setting true, You should declare dependency of ear on each module that needed someone...

Comment: Other tips, the problem is with taglib uri  `http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles` and `/struts-tags`, I have review setting of struts2 and tiles and all is ok, I comments bouth taglib element and dont get error, the request is completed without exception, I have clean and re build el project and continue  problem...

Answer (score 0):

My problem in detail was for some reason some jar file that they are calling from the modules dont are avalible in the project deploy. Then, I did a simple modify jboss-deployment-structure.xml and all good.

I added meta-inf="export" property.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <!-- <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment> -->
    <sub-deployment name="project.war">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="own.org.apache.tiles" meta-inf="export" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.struts2" meta-inf="export" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.commons" meta-inf="export" />
            <module name="own.org.apache.logging" meta-inf="export" />
            <module name="own.freemarker" meta-inf="export" />
            <module name="own.javassist" meta-inf="export" />
            <module name="own.ognl" meta-inf="export" />
        </dependencies>
    <!-- <exclusions>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions> -->
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```